Measuring time in C on Windows OS
I am measuring elapsed time using gettimeofday function and I would compare times measured in different codes in order to decide which code is faster. I know that the measured time is in general different on each run. I read that the difference could be even of 30%. Well... I noticed that in my case the difference can reach the 1000% too. So, how can I have a sufficiently estimate of the time spent in the code? I could made several runs of the same code and mediate the measured time, the average should be more precise of the single measure. But I noticed that the number of repetition should be very large in order not to obtain very different values even for the mean time when it is measured different times. I wonder if I have to test a code that requires many seconds for a single run.
So, how do you decide with sufficiently precision which code is faster than another?
In the following I post an example of what I am saying, in which I am measuring the time spent in the inner for cycle. In order to have a mean time not widely spreaded I have to use M=100000. Any suggestions (not too difficult to implement) to make the measured time more precise with less repetitions?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

double *Vec(int n)
{
    double *p = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    assert(p != NULL);
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    int N = 10000;
    int M = 100000;
    double* v = Vec(N);
    double* t = Vec(M);
    struct timeval begin, end;

    srand(time(0));

    for (int j=0; j<M; j++) 
    {
        gettimeofday(&begin, 0);
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            v[i] = rand() % 100;
            //v[i] = rand()*100/(RAND_MAX +1.0);
        }
        gettimeofday(&end, 0);
        long seconds = end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec;
        long microseconds = end.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec;
        t[j] = seconds + microseconds*1e-6;
    }
    double tmean = 0;
    for (int j=0; j<M; j++)
    {
        tmean += t[j]/M;
    }
    printf("Mean time: %.6f ms.\n", tmean*1000);

    free(v);
    free(t);

    return 0;
}


Yes, it's best to time the code for at least a second. The timing should be outside the outer loop, making sure the job isn't optimised away. Rather than trying to take averages of the inner loop.

... you are timing only 10000 fairly simple operations, and not using what it does. Time the entire job, and divide by the repetitions.

Variations of 1000% could be caused by external activity. Before running your program, bring up task manager and sort by CPU. End tasks at top of list that are not needed for you or for your OS to run. Review activity in other fields looking for activities that could impact your timing study - for example too high disk activity, network traffic, etc. Shutting down browsers could also help.

Not sure if this will help since your array sizes are relatively small with the amount of free physical memory you have: Initialize your two Vec's to zero's before going into your outer loop. This will remove any doubt about paging issues taking up some initial time. (I assumed you have lots of available memory - in task manager, select Performance --> Memory --> Available to verify while you are running the test.)

To initialize the two arrays, use calloc instead of malloc.

Updated the code with the two suggestions: make the time measurement outside the outer loop dividing by the repetitions and initialized the vector at the beginning. I don't know if this is a random fact due to different background processes, but I see that now the time average seems more stable.

Why should I use calloc?

Good, but please don't make rolling changes to the posted code, or it will become a "shifting sand" question with irrelevant comments.

Ok, sorry. I saw many others updating their code after the comments, so I made so :D

Usually, the post is updated for clarification, or additional information. Do you get that if you end up posting the answer, where is the question? This isn't a tutorial forum. However, you can post a self-answer to your own question, leaving it intact so that future readers can follow the plot.

@D.alfano - Why should I use calloc? On a RHEL system where we were measuring durations, we found that if we didn't initialize our large 2d arrays, then our measurements for the first time we hit an allocated memory page, RHEL had to bring in the page into physical memory. This is an expensive disk operation. We didn't want the process startup time to be part of our alg timing measurement. After we touched each page, the 2d array was not completely in memory for many subsequent hits. TBH, I don't know whether this same principle applies to Windows, but it doesn't hurt for the initialization.

On Windows you can use few methods:
\

Processor Timestamp Counter (resolution : cycle-level - nanoseconds)

unsigned long long rdtsc() 
{
    unsigned int lo, hi;
    __asm__ __volatile__("cpuid" ::: "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
    __asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return ((unsigned long long)hi << 32) | lo;
}

/* ... */

    unsigned long long start, end;
    start = rdtsc();
    functionToMeasure();
    end = rdtsc();

or if the intrinsic function is available (MSVC)
    unsigned long long start, end;
    start = __rdtsc();
    functionToMeasure();
    end = __rdtsc()


Using QueryPerformanceCounter (High-Resolution Timer) (sub µs resolution).

Example:
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void functionToMeasure() 
{
    Sleep(2);
}

int main() 
{
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency, start, end;
    double elapsedTime;

    
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
    functionToMeasure();
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);

    elapsedTime = (double)(end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) * 1000.0 / frequency.QuadPart;

    printf("Execution time: %.3f ms\n", elapsedTime);
    return 0;
}


GetTickCount64 (ms resolution)

   DWORD64 start, end;
    start = GetTickCount64();
    functionToMeasure();
    end = GetTickCount64();


<time.h>  functions (10-15ms resolution)

    clock_t start, end;
    double elapsedTime;

    start = clock();
    functionToMeasure();
    end = clock();

    elapsedTime = ((double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) * 1000.0;

    printf("Execution time: %.3f ms\n", elapsedTime);

You can also use QueryThreadCycleTime

Thank you, I'll try the other method (I already used GetTickCount64 but it gives me always 0 and I don't know why). But... are you telling me that the method I used is incorrect or not precise with respect to these?

Since I couldn't find <sys/time.h> on my Windows laptop using build toolchain: C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30154 for x86, I used <time.h> instead. I came up with two versions, and will try a third approach (time-permitting).
In both cases, I used M = 30 and N = 10000 and got stable results (even with the timer within the inner loop) with the following issue:
Caveat: The timespec field, tv_nsec, is good for timing very short segments. If the segment is too long, then tv_nsec will overflow and results can even appear negative. On the other hand, when the timed section is short, then using the tv_sec field can result in a zero difference due to lack of enough significant bits. So, be wary of your results.
Approach using tv_nsec:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
// #include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

double *Vec(int n)
{
    double *p = (double*)calloc(n, sizeof(double));
    assert(p != NULL);
    return p;
}

int main(void)
{
    int N = 10000;
    int M = 30;
    double* v = Vec(N);
    double* duration_nSec = Vec(M); // save nano-seconds
    double min_ns = 1e100;
    double max_ns = 0;

    printf(" M = %d  N = %d;  ", M, N);

    srand(99);

    struct timespec start, stop;

    for (int jj=0; jj<M; jj++)  
    {
        if( timespec_get(&start, TIME_UTC) != TIME_UTC ) { printf("abort\n"); return -1;}
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            v[i] += pow(11, (rand() % 100) * (rand() % 101)) * pow(3, (rand() % 103)* (rand() % 107) );
            v[i] += pow(11, (rand() % 100) * (rand() % 101)) * pow(3, (rand() % 103)* (rand() % 107) );
        }
        if( timespec_get(&stop, TIME_UTC) != TIME_UTC ) { printf("abort\n"); return -1;}

        duration_nSec[jj] = (stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);
    }

    double tmean_nSec = 0;
    for (int kk=0; kk<M; kk++)
    {
        tmean_nSec += duration_nSec[kk];
        if( duration_nSec[kk] < min_ns )
        {
            min_ns = duration_nSec[kk];
        }
        if( duration_nSec[kk] > max_ns )
        {
            max_ns = duration_nSec[kk];
        }
    }
    tmean_nSec = tmean_nSec/M;
    double tmean_uSec = tmean_nSec / 1e6; // convert to mSec

    printf("Mean time: %.3f ms.  min ms = %.3f  max ms = %.3f\n", tmean_uSec, min_ns / 1e6, max_ns / 1e6);

    free(v);
    free(duration_nSec);

    return 0;
}

Output:
C:\Users\C> .\measureTime2.exe   
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 2.876 ms.  min ms = 2.605  max ms = 3.262
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 2.938 ms.  min ms = 2.609  max ms = 3.168
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 2.907 ms.  min ms = 2.656  max ms = 3.330
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 3.303 ms.  min ms = 2.702  max ms = 3.669
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 2.894 ms.  min ms = 2.622  max ms = 3.164
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 2.897 ms.  min ms = 2.618  max ms = 3.166
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 2.931 ms.  min ms = 2.668  max ms = 3.367
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 3.011 ms.  min ms = 2.662  max ms = 3.256
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 2.887 ms.  min ms = 2.624  max ms = 3.184
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 2.899 ms.  min ms = 2.554  max ms = 3.345
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 3.205 ms.  min ms = 2.754  max ms = 3.498
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 3.074 ms.  min ms = 2.643  max ms = 3.397
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 3.136 ms.  min ms = 2.711  max ms = 4.478

The other approach uses clock():
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
// #include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

double *Vec(int n)
{
    double *p = (double*)calloc(n, sizeof(double));
    assert(p != NULL);
    return p;
}

int main(void)
{
    int N = 10000;
    int M = 30;
    double* v = Vec(N);
    double* t_clocks = Vec(M); // save micro-seconds
    double min_clocks = 1e100;
    double max_clocks = 0;

    printf(" M = %d  N = %d;  ", M, N);

    srand(99);

    for (int j=0; j<M; j++)  
    {
        clock_t start = clock();
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            v[i] += pow(11, (rand() % 100) * (rand() % 101)) * pow(3, (rand() % 103)* (rand() % 107) );
            v[i] += pow(11, (rand() % 100) * (rand() % 101)) * pow(3, (rand() % 103)* (rand() % 107) );
        }
        clock_t stop = clock();

        t_clocks[j] = (stop - start);
    }

    double tmean_clocks = 0;
    for (int j=0; j<M; j++)
    {
        tmean_clocks += t_clocks[j];
        if( t_clocks[j] < min_clocks )
        {
            min_clocks = t_clocks[j];
        }
        if( t_clocks[j] > max_clocks )
        {
            max_clocks = t_clocks[j];
        }
    }
    tmean_clocks = tmean_clocks/M;
    double tmean_ms = (tmean_clocks / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) * 1000; // milliseconds

    printf("Mean time: %.6f ms.  min_clocks = %.2f  max_clocks = %.2f\n", tmean_ms, min_clocks, max_clocks);

    free(v);
    free(t_clocks);

    return 0;
}

Output:
PS C:\Users\C> .\measureTime.exe   
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 2.833333 ms.  min_clocks = 2.00  max_clocks = 4.00
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 3.266667 ms.  min_clocks = 2.00  max_clocks = 4.00
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 3.000000 ms.  min_clocks = 2.00  max_clocks = 4.00
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 3.266667 ms.  min_clocks = 3.00  max_clocks = 4.00
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 2.966667 ms.  min_clocks = 2.00  max_clocks = 4.00
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 3.200000 ms.  min_clocks = 2.00  max_clocks = 4.00
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 3.033333 ms.  min_clocks = 2.00  max_clocks = 4.00
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 3.300000 ms.  min_clocks = 3.00  max_clocks = 4.00
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 3.100000 ms.  min_clocks = 2.00  max_clocks = 4.00
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 2.900000 ms.  min_clocks = 2.00  max_clocks = 4.00
 M = 30  N = 10000;  Mean time: 2.866667 ms.  min_clocks = 2.00  max_clocks = 4.00


Thank you for your reply. Actually the line  #include <sys/time.h>  is underlined in red on my Visual Studio but it compiles anyway. However I tried your way using clock() (DIVIDING the result by CLOCKS_PER_SEC and not MULTIPLYING it :D) and I experienced the same deviation of the mean time: I have to use the same M of before to get a stable mean time. However I didn't modified the inner for cycle as you have done.

Division is correct - my bad. I changed the inner loop computation to only two lines; added the pow() function to be computationally heavier than just the multiplication and modulo. For me CLOCKS_PER_SEC is 1000. With a min/max clocks of 2/4 clocks, that's only 2 ms apart. With less heavy computation, sometimes min == max; and this is OK if averaging over large number of iterations. Given the clock duration was showing mostly 2ms, it is not surprising the the clock approach produced mean times of approximately 3 ms.

Since  you are using Visual Studio, take a look at their profiler. I have used performance profilers in Linux, but not in MS VS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/cpu-usage?view=vs-2022
